# how to interpret assembly and write it as risc-like micro ops

Tags: c, assembly, x86, cpu-architecture

I am learning assembly and came across this practice.

the book i am using is : Randal E. Bryant, David R. O’Hallaron - Computer Systems. A Programmer’s Perspective [3rd ed.] (2016, Pearson)

I am given this piece of assembly code for the inner loop of the C code where there is an accumulation calculation done to calculate r. Using AT&T.

```
L3:
    mulsd   (%rcx,%rax,8), %xmm0     
    mulsd   8(%rcx,%rax,8), %xmm0    
    mulsd   16(%rcx,%rax,8), %xmm0   
    addq    $3, %rax                        
    cmpq    %r8, %rax                
    jl      .L3
```

And this is the corresponding C code

```
double randomproduct(double a[], long n)
{
    long i;
    double x, y, z;
    double r=1;
    for (i=0; i<n-2; i+=3) {
        x = a[i]; y = a[i+1]; z = a[i+2];
        r = r*x*y*z; //accumulation calc
    }
    for (; i<n; i++)
        r *= a[i];
    return r;
}
```

I am not sure how I should go about with writing this in RISC-like micro -ops for at least a couple of iterations.

This is what I have currently:

```
load r0, (rcx,rax,8)  //r0 is the loading register to store the data from the [array+i*8] calculation
mul r0,rax,rax //not sure if the name and order of the registers are correct I'm pretty lost :(
```

I'm really confused about what registers/memory locations should be used for this and how RISC-like micro ops shd be written.
Please send help, all help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The only multiplies here are on `double` operands, so the ALU uop will be `mulsd` with XMM vector operands, not integer `mul`.  Note that mulsd leaves the upper half of its destination register unchanged, but that's fine (no false dependency) because is already reads from that register as an input.  Unlike `sqrtsd` or `cvtsi2sd` unfortunately...  Those uops still have two input operands, and a destination.

Comment: As far as how they should be *written*, Intel hasn't published anything about developing microcode, so you're basically making up syntax.  It probably makes the most sense to use a 2-operand format for normal instructions like mulsd, at least if you're describing them before the issue/rename stage allocates a separate physical register for each new version of an architectural register.

Comment: @PeterCordes I see! And what are the registers that should be used when dealing with xmm? I think I am confused b/w what is a register here and what is a memory location? Appreciate the help!

Comment: You may get better answers if you add some context. What RISC uOPs are you talking about? Intel's internal, and not documented, list of uOPs? Something the book makeup as a learning tool? Does the book just want you to separate the loads from the vector operations?

Comment: @MargaretBloom, yes, it's the last option you suggested. the book has this as a practice to separate each load, mul, store for understanding of how each iteration has their instructions carried out by the functional units.

Comment: The architectural xmm registers are xmm0 through xmm15.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#x86_registers. In the front-end (decoders and uop cache), that's what uops reference. (There may be one or two reserved for internal use by microcode; there are some hidden/internal GPRs as per Henry Wong's research: https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/05/measuring-rob-capacity/).  Internally, Haswell renames them onto a 168-entry physical register file, so the backend versions of uops reference those.  (https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/3/).

Comment: You can just make up the name of an internal register, say `buf0` and then write something like `load64 buf0, (rcx, rax, 8) / mulsd xmm0, xmm0, buf0` and similar for the three `mulsd`. The point here is that the CPU will bring the 64-bit memory operand into an internal register and then reduce the case to a multiplication where all the operands are registers. If the book intended you to use only architectural registers then it's like restricting yourself to write assembly with no memory operand but for loads/stores. Something like: `movq xmm1, (rcx, rax, 8) / mulsd xmm0, xmm0, xmm1`.

Comment: A really RISC-like machine would probably need separate shift and add instructions to generate the effective address `(%rcx, %rax, 8)`, which is `rcx + (rax << 3)`, in a register.  So probably first a `shl r1, rax, 3 ; add r1, rcx ; load r0, (r1)`.

Comment: @NateEldredge: classic RISC CPUs in the style of MIPS usually only have one memory addressing mode, and that's `reg + immediate`.  But some do have indexed loads (like PowerPC), and ARM / AArch64 have even more powerful addressing modes that include scaled indexes.  The point of decoding to uops is to reduce to things that one execution can do, and it's easily possible to build an AGU that can shift and add, so in this context there's no need to impose RISC philosophical purity on them.  (But yes, interesting point.)